# Is it possible to append data specific columns of existing csv using JMETER?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, export-to-csv, load-testing, beanshell

I have an existing csv file with some data stored. I need to append data in specific columns of csv using jmeter.

Example :

[image]

I need to append data in column C and E of this existing csv file.
Is it possible to do this with Jmeter? If yes, how can we do the same

Answer (score 1):

There is no such a thing as "column" in the CSV file, however you can read lines one by one and replace them with the lines containing new values for `age` and `department_id`

For example if you have [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) like:

```
age_1=35
age_2=29
department_id_1=100
department_id_1=200
etc.
```

you can add the above variables to your CSV file using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following code snippet:

```
def lines = new File('/path/to/your/file.csv').readLines()

1.upto(lines.size() - 1, { lineNo ->
    def values = new String[5]
    def entries = lines.get(lineNo).split(',')
    entries.eachWithIndex { entry, idx ->
        values[idx] = entry
    }
    values[2] = vars.get('age_' + lineNo)
    values[4] = vars.get('department_id_' + lineNo)
    lines.putAt(lineNo, values.join(','))
})

org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.writeLines(new File('/path/to/your/file.csv'), lines, false)
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)